# Cannot get basic auth to work on nginx on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, authentication

I can't seem to get basic auth to work on nginx.  Can anyone suggest what is wrong?

Permissions/ownership of .htpasswd

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-GB-BXi3-5010:~$ sudo ls -lah /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
-r-xr-x--- 1 root www-data 45 Aug  6 13:22 /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
```

Contents of .htpasswd

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-GB-BXi3-5010:~$ sudo cat /etc/nginx/.htpasswd
robert:$apr1$v6WW9OCq$gRlr0640ZnacROOpyGzsQ0
```

Contents of default site for nginx

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-GB-BXi3-5010:~$ sudo cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;
    location /api {
      auth_basic           "Restricted";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
      return 201;
    }
}
```

Make sure nginx is restarted:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-GB-BXi3-5010:~$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Send a request to the server via CURL with verbose switched on, the resulting 201 code comes straight back - no basic auth information was sent to the server:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-GB-BXi3-5010:~$ curl --verbose http://127.0.0.1/api
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Server: nginx/1.16.0
< Date: Tue, 06 Aug 2019 03:23:26 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

nginx version is 1.16.0

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-GB-BXi3-5010:~$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.16.0
```

nginx installed modules:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-GB-BXi3-5010:~$ nginx -V 2>&1 | tr -- - '\n' | grep module
modules
path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules
http_addition_module
http_auth_request_module
http_dav_module
http_flv_module
http_gunzip_module
http_gzip_static_module
http_mp4_module
http_random_index_module
http_realip_module
http_secure_link_module
http_slice_module
http_ssl_module
http_stub_status_module
http_sub_module
http_v2_module
mail_ssl_module
stream_realip_module
stream_ssl_module
stream_ssl_preread_module
ubuntu@ubuntu-GB-BXi3-5010:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course after hours, as soon as I post on SO I find the answer:

It appears that the basic auth directives need to be at the bottom of the location block, for reasons I do not understand:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;
    location /api {
      return 201;
      auth_basic           "Restricted";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```